# Flex item is stretched by Chrome to fill cross axis but not by Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox

The markup and styling given at the end of this description produce different views in Chrome and Firefox (as the following snapshot shows).

[image]

Chrome stretches the image inside `cancel-icon` div to take full height of the parent but Firefox keeps the image at original height. To keep things consistent i had to specify image width (commented lines in the styling code below).

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #DA291F;
  height: 40px;

}
.timer-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #313131;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .cancel-icon {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  /* .cancel-icon img {
    width: 20px;
  } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="timer-text">
        <div>00:00:00</div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="cancel-icon">
        <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/mmR.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a runnable snippet so we can see the problem as at the moment I cannot recreate your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: @a-haworth fiddle link added to the issue description. Apologies for the delay. Btw, i also noticed that this issue was not reproducing with another image i tried. So, could it be something image specific ?

Comment: @A Haworth are you able to find the jsfiddle ?

Comment: Please put your code direct into your question, not on an external site. And please check that it does indeed show the problem.

Comment: @A Haworth done. I think the issue is manifesting if u run it on Chrome VS FF. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I inspected the elements in both browsers and did some research, and found the reason that causes this is **User-agent stylesheets**.

**What are User-agent stylesheets?**

User-agent, or browsers, have basic style sheets that give default styles to any document. These style sheets are named user-agent stylesheets. Most browsers use actual stylesheets for this purpose, while others simulate them in code. The end result is the same.

to see all related details you can check it here on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets)

**So, what to do about it?**

Some developers suggest using a CSS reset stylesheet, such as [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css). I actually tried it with your code but didn't work in your case. Also if you use it, then you will need to use a lot of `!important` in your CSS code.

**What should I do then?**

If you leave anything without style, then User-agent stylesheets will style it for you according to each browser.

In your case, I found that it happened because you didn't give your `SVG` any height and width, and that's why chrome user agent stylesheet styled it for you.

I also noticed that it happened because of the `display flex` for its parent.

After I tried some solutions, I found the easiest solution is to add `align-items: center;` to the `SVG` parent.

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #DA291F;
  height: 40px;

}
.timer-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #313131;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .cancel-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  /* .cancel-icon img {
    width: 20px;
  } */
```

```html
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="timer-text">
        <div>00:00:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cancel-icon">
        <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/mmR.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers support is a big problem and you must consider that in every development and design you do. and sometimes you can't just do what you want, otherwise it won't be supported in all browsers. So I suggest you to use png instead of SVG and give it a specific hight and it will be the same size in all browsers.

```css
.content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #DA291F;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
  
  }
  .timer-text {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      color: #313131;
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
    .cancel-icon {
      display: flex;
      padding: 0 5px;
      height: 80%;
    }
    /* .cancel-icon img {
      width: 20px;
    } */
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="timer-text">
        <div>00:00:00</div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="cancel-icon">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-tanah-basah-glyph-tanah-basah/344/external-stop-multimedia-tanah-basah-glyph-tanah-basah.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: i know that explicitly setting a dimension of the image or its parent works. The question is why does chrome stretch the image to fill row height but Firefox does not when the actual image height is smaller than the row height.

Comment: I mean when the actual image height is smaller than the parent (`.cancel-icon` class) height and we don't apply explicit height on the image or the parent (flex item).

Comment: @oomer I added another answer. please check it out. and don't forget to upvote and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: using png is not necessary, giving the image (whether svg or png) an explicit height fixes the problem and is already mentioned in my original post. The main thing i wanted to find an answer for was why Chrome and FF treat this issue differently.

Comment: My bad, i just read your new answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73960709/4997994, and i will at least upvote it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flex-grow: 1` to `.cancel-icon` should work. Depending on main/cross axis, an element should grow horizontally/vertically with `flex-grow` set to 1.

By default `flex-grow` **= 0**, meaning that the element is not allowed to grow. I am not sure why Chrome does not honor that. However, despite the same code base as Chrome, Edge does.

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #DA291F;
  height: 40px;
}

.timer-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #313131;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.cancel-icon {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* ADD */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="timer-text">
      <div>00:00:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cancel-icon">
      <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/mmR.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```